# Python - New list of permutations with omissions

Tags: python, permutation

Lets say I have a list of values

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
```

I user `itertools.permutations` to find all combinations of this list

```
perms = itertools.permutations(my_list)
```

Which creates

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4),
(1, 2, 4, 3),
(1, 3, 2, 4),
(1, 3, 4, 2),
(1, 4, 2, 3),
(1, 4, 3, 2),
(2, 1, 3, 4),
(2, 1, 4, 3),
(2, 3, 1, 4),
(2, 3, 4, 1),
(2, 4, 1, 3),
(2, 4, 3, 1),
(3, 1, 2, 4),
(3, 1, 4, 2),
(3, 2, 1, 4),
(3, 2, 4, 1),
(3, 4, 1, 2),
(3, 4, 2, 1),
(4, 1, 2, 3),
(4, 1, 3, 2),
(4, 2, 1, 3),
(4, 2, 3, 1),
(4, 3, 1, 2),
(4, 3, 2, 1)]
```

I begin iterating through this and find that I no longer need any items in `perms` which begin with `(4,1...` or `(3,1...`.

How can I recreate this list with those specific omissions? Iterating through and removing items is not viable as this needs to scale to very large sizes.

EDIT: For clarification `(4,1,2,3)` should be removed as it starts with `(4,1...)`, but not `(4,2,1,3)` as it starts with `(4,2...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you state

> Iterating through and removing items is not viable as this needs to
>   scale to very large sizes.

The best is to wrap the interator produced by `permutations` that will generate the tuples you want and skip the tuples you do not want:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]

def my_perms(my_list, f):
    for e in permutations(my_list):
        if f(e):
            yield e 

>>> list(my_perms(my_list, lambda t: t[:2] not in {(4,1), (3,1)}))
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 4, 3), (2, 3, 1, 4), (2, 3, 4, 1), (2, 4, 1, 3), (2, 4, 3, 1), (3, 2, 1, 4), (3, 2, 4, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2), (3, 4, 2, 1), (4, 2, 1, 3), (4, 2, 3, 1), (4, 3, 1, 2), (4, 3, 2, 1)]
```

Or, use [ifilter from itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter):

```
>>> list(ifilter(lambda t: t[:2] not in {(4,1), (3,1)}, permutations(my_list)))
```

Or, filter directly on Python 3+ since that also creates an iterator vs creating a list as filter on Python 2 does.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4]
>>> perms = permutations(my_list)
>>> perms
<itertools.permutations object at 0x107a63ad0>
>>> perms = filter(lambda x: x[:2] != (4,1) and x[:2] != (3,1), perms)
>>> perms
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 4, 3), (2, 3, 1, 4), (2, 3, 4, 1), (2, 4, 1, 3), (2, 4, 3, 1), (3, 2, 1, 4), (3, 2, 4, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2), (3, 4, 2, 1), (4, 2, 1, 3), (4, 2, 3, 1), (4, 3, 1, 2), (4, 3, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: On Python 2, `filter` will create the list which is not what the OP stated he wanted. At least point out `ifilter` as a more memory friendly way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to get the expected permutations :

```
>>> [i for i in perms if i[0] not in {3,4}]
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 4, 3), (2, 3, 1, 4), (2, 3, 4, 1), (2, 4, 1, 3), (2, 4, 3, 1)]
```

Note that using a `set` container has O(1) for check the membership.and it would be more efficient if you have more filter numbers!

If you don't want the tuples that starts with `3,1` and `4,1` you can just simply do :

```
>>> perms = it.permutations(my_list)
>>> [i for i in perms if i[:2] !=[4,1] and i[:2] !=[4,1]]
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 4, 3), (2, 3, 1, 4), (2, 3, 4, 1), (2, 4, 1, 3), (2, 4, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2, 4), (3, 1, 4, 2), (3, 2, 1, 4), (3, 2, 4, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2), (3, 4, 2, 1), (4, 1, 2, 3), (4, 1, 3, 2), (4, 2, 1, 3), (4, 2, 3, 1), (4, 3, 1, 2), (4, 3, 2, 1)]
>>>
```

Comment: This is wrong I think, you omit all tuples starting with 3 and 4.

Comment: @laike9m I think its what that OP wants otherwise it doesn't make any difference because the recipe is important!

Comment: What I am looking for is the removal of anything starting with `(3,1..)` or `(4,1...)`. E.g. `(4,1,2,3)` should be removed, but not `(4,2,1,3)`